# Why does manually computed weibull hazard not match formula?

Tags: survival, hazard, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to understand survival analysis better and ran into a weird problem with hazard rates - when I calculate it by hand,
i.e. with

$$
h(t) = \left( \frac{ P(T \leq t + \Delta t) - P(T \leq t)}{S(t)  \Delta t}\right)
$$

it doesn't line up with the formula for a hazard rate, given by

$$
h(t) = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}
$$

here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

def hazard_manual(k, lambd, t, dt=1):
    dist = stats.weibull_min(k, scale=lambd)
    return (
        ((dist.cdf(t+dt) - dist.cdf(t)) / dt) 
        * (1/dist.sf(t))
    )

def hazard(k, lambd, t):
    dist=stats.weibull_min(k, scale=lambd)
    return dist.pdf(t)/dist.sf(t)

k, lambd = 1.5, 30

manual_haz = hazard_manual(k, lambd, t=40)
haz = hazard(k, lambd, t=40)
print(
    f"Manually calculated hazard = {round(manual_haz,5)}",
    f"\nHazard from formula = {round(haz,5)}",
)
```

```
Manually calculated hazard = 0.05644 
Hazard from formula = 0.05774
```

And I did an additional simulation data which aligns with the manual calculation

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


dist = stats.weibull_min(k,scale=lambd)

t = 40
dt=1

boots = []
for sim in range(100):
    T = dist.rvs(10_000_000)
    events_gt40 = T[T>t]
    events = (events_gt40 < (t+dt))
    boots.append(events.mean())

sns.histplot(boots)
plt.axvline(manual_haz, ls="--", label="Manually Calculated Hazard Rate", lw=3)
plt.axvline(haz, ls="--", label="Hazard from formula", color="C1", lw=3)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

so **why doesnt the actual formula match? Is it wrong? Does it have a slightly different interpretation? If so what?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a more specific answer to this, you can find the probability of an event occurring between times [t, dt] by taking $CDF(t+dt) - CDF(t)$, and then divide that by the probability of reaching time t

so if instantaneous hazard is

$$
h(t) = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}
$$

then discrete hazard is

$$
h(t) = \frac{F(t+1)-F(t)}{S(t)}
$$

and in python

```py
def discrete_hazard(k, lambd, t):
    dist=stats.weibull_min(k, scale=lambd)
    discrete_pdf = (dist.cdf(t+1) - dist.cdf(t))
    return discrete_pdf/dist.sf(t)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get the correct value as $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, as that's the definition of derivatives.

Right now, you are using `dt = 1`, which is very large. You should be getting the average derivative over the region [40, 41], but it can change a lot in that interval. I'd suggest using `dt=0.0001`. It'll still be an approximation, but it should be much closer.

Comment: you're right, it is much closer - so what use is the actual instantaneous hazard function if my task might be to calculate the probability of event in the next 1,2,...n discrete time periods?  It seems like it overestimates in every instance

Comment: @Kylejcaron if your task is to calculate the probability of an event during a time period, you would be better off using differences of the _cumulative_ hazard $H(t)$ over the time period rather than working with the instantaneous hazard that you are trying to calculate, or use the survival function $S(t)=\exp(-H(t))$ directly.